# Unable to sort array in alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I am currently trying to sort an array alphabetically
I am having **troubles with step 3**. Here is my current code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import hsa.Console;

public class HowToSortAnArray {
    static Console c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c = new Console ();

        String[] myStrArray = new String[500];

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            c.print("Input word: ");
            myStrArray[i]=c.readLine();
        }

        Arrays.sort(myStrArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        for (int a = 0; a < myStrArray.length; a++) {
           c.println(myStrArray[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this code isn't working an this one is:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"b", "b", "a", "D"};
Arrays.sort(words, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

for (int a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
    c.println(words[a]);
}
```

Does it have something to do with declaring array values? I am pretty lost.

Comment: are you getting a `NullPointerException` ? I get one at at `java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)`. I believe it happens when it hits a non initialized location

Comment: for(int i=0;i>5;i++) {   --> for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

Comment: sorry, i quickly rushed and didn't see that. But the error still occurs.

Comment: a <= myStrArray.length instead of < and also do a trim() on your input to avoid blank spaces ....          myStrArray[i]=c.readLine(); is the problem line for me

Comment: the problem is that if you initialize the array statically you can't be sure that the whole array has been filled up. When the comparator has to compare something with null it raises a null pointer exception. I can tell that your code will raise one if you enter the sequence: {test, test}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your line to:

```
 for(int i=0;i<myStrArray.length;i++);





import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HowToSortAnArray {
static Console c;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] myStrArray = new String[5];

    for(int i=0;i<myStrArray.length;i++) {
         System.out.println("Input word: ");
        myStrArray[i]= "abdfg";
    }

    Arrays.sort(myStrArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    for (int a = 0; a < myStrArray.length; a++) {
         System.out.println(myStrArray[a]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: All you are doing is setting the value of abdfg to every single array index. You are not even asking for an input.

Comment: I eliminated the input as a possible problem. clearly the problem is in the input

Comment: I asked another question in relation to this one, simplified http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208585/remove-all-null-array-values-before-sorting

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> wordsSet = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Input word: ");
            String newLine = s.nextLine();
            if (!wordsSet.add(newLine)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        String[] words = wordsSet.toArray(new String[wordsSet.size()]);
        Arrays.sort(words, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
        return;
    }
}
```

You can use `java.util.Set` to make sure that there are no duplicates. `java.util.Set.add` returns false if what you are adding is already present in the set, so you can use this as a condition to exit the input-enter loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your hsa.Console with a java.io.Console will fix your errors. I.e.

```
import java.io.Console;

...

c = System.console();

...
```

Then use c.printf(...) instead of c.println().

Comment: Yes his input method is def causing the issues. When I elminated the input in my version it worked 100%